# NSnumber in to NSstring

Tags: nsstring, nsnumber

```
Stock *stockObject;

stockObject = [[Stock alloc]initWithIssuingCompany:addCompany stockName:@"one" stockPrice:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:150.3]];       

[availableStocks addObject:stockObject];


float myfloat = [s.stockPrice floatValue];
```

NSLog(@"singleton@%f", myfloat);

Try this code but it will crush on:

```
float myfloat = [s.stockPrice floatValue];
```

no error.

Can some one help me?

Comment: Where does s.stockPrice come from? Should that be stockObject.stockPrice? Also, you may want to clean up your code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be `[stockObject.stockPric floatValue]` ?